# Negative Predictions in Linear Regression with Boston Housing Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am working on predicting housing prices using the Boston Housing dataset and have encountered an issue where my model, a simple linear regression, is predicting negative values for certain inputs.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Loading the data and selecting features
df = data.drop("medv", axis = "columns")
X = data[["rm", "lstat", "ptratio"]]
y = data['medv']

# Splitting the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# Training the model
reg_all = LinearRegression()
reg = reg_all.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Making predictions and evaluating the model
y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
print("R-squared:", reg.score(X_test,y_test))
print("RMSE:", mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred, squared = False))

# Making a prediction for a new client
d = {"rm": [4], 'lstat': [32], "ptratio" : [22] }
df_predict = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
predict_client = reg.predict(df_predict)
print("Prediction for client:", predict_client)
```

For the new client with 'rm' = 4, 'lstat' = 32, and 'ptratio' = 22, the model is predicting negative values, which doesn't make sense in the context of housing prices.

What could be causing these negative predictions and how can I correct for this?

Comment: Have you checked if negative values are present in the training dataset or not ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, why this could be the case:

- The new input could be not in the range of the existings paramets, i would check the range of the input data with something like:

```
data['rm'].min(), data['rm'].max()
```

If the new client is not in the range, the negative values can be logical, as the linear regression always at some point will have negativ values.
for example imagen the input data is on the left side of the x-axis:
[image]

- I would check if the dataframe has some negativ values inside, only because its the boston houseprice dataset does not mean that the values only are positive

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you normalized your training data? if so apply scaler.transform on inference data